# Tomcat JSP requests consumes all of heap space

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, heap-memory

I am in the process of trying to a memory leak in our Tomcat Java web application and thought I had found it when making repeated requests to one of our JSPs. However, after stripping it down to a single, empty JSP dropped into an out-of-the-box Tomcat 6.0.37 instance running on jdk1.6, I still see the same thing.

I am starting Tomcat with a max heap size (-Xmx) of 256m, and the heap runs out of space after around 282,000 requests made by my test class below.

For comparison, I also created an HttpServlet that does the same thing as the JSP and modified my test client to call that instead, and that will run all day without running out of memory.

I have started trying to analyze the heap to figure out what's going on here, but not really getting anywhere. Soooo, what's going on here??

**Test JSP**

```
<%@ page language="java" import="java.util.*" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page contentType="text/plain"%>
<% System.out.println("Page requested: " + new Date()); %>
This is a test response
```

**Java Test Client**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  int i=0;
  while(true) {
    java.net.URL url = new java.net.URL("http://localhost:8080/test.jsp");
    InputStream is = url.openStream();
    while(is.read() != -1) {
      //nothing, just read the stream
    }
    is.close();
    System.out.println("Requests made: " + i++);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JSP requests implicitly creates the HTTP session. You're not maintaining the HTTP session in your HTTP client and therefore a whole new HTTP session is created on every request. Those sessions have an expire time of by default 30 minutes. Apparently all those requests were fired within 30 minutes.

You would face exactly the same problem in a servlet when you do `request.getSession()` in the servlet method.

In order to "fix" this "problem" (which is unlikely to happen in real world; 282K concurrent HTTP sessions on a barebones Tomcat instance is on the other hand pretty respectable), either disable implicit creation of HTTP session in JSP:

```
<%@page session="false">
```

or tell client to reuse the same HTTP session by maintaining the cookies by the following line *before* the `while` loop:

```
CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager(null, CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL));
```

An alternative is to decrease the session timeout so that the server gets the chance to reap them before it causes heap to overflow, e.g. to 5 minutes as follows in `web.xml`:

```xml
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>5</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

You can implement a `HttpSessionListener` to track the HTTP session creation and destroy.

Comment: ahhh, that makes sense. I see there are roughly as many `StandardSession` objects in my heap as requests that were made. and you are right, this is not the "real world problem," but understanding this helps me adjust my tests to hopefully find the actual problem.

Comment: You're welcome. A profiler may be more helpful on finding the actual problem.